# Can't able maven install

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, spring-boot, jar

I had been created a jar from my Java project using Eclipse IDE.
Then I have added that jar into my spring boot maven project's build path.
When I am trying to maven clean and install after adding my custom jar, I can't able to run maven install successfully.
I am getting below error,

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project springBootExample: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] error reading C:\Users\VAIBHAV-PC\.m2\repository\org\hsqldb\hsqldb\2.3.3\hsqldb-2.3.3.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature)
[ERROR] /D:springBootExample/src/main/java/com/springBootExample/service/impl/UserServiceImpl.java:[9,29] package com.ResponceGenerator does not exist
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException.
```

Comment: This seems pertinent: [ERROR] error reading C:\Users\VAIBHAV-PC.m2\repository\org\hsqldb\hsqldb\2.3.3\hsqldb-2.3.3.jar; invalid LOC header (bad signature) [ERROR].  Follow the error message and run with the -X switch turned on.  You'll get more information.  I think Maven is find.  It's your local .m2 repo that has a problem.

Comment: remove `C:\Users\VAIBHAV-PC.m2\repository\org\hsqldb\hsqldb\2.3.3` folder and try again.

Comment: `VAIBHAV-PC.m2` looks strange. Probably wrong setup of maven repository folder. How do you invoke maven? Also check `settings.xml`.

Comment: I had downloaded  hsqldb-2.3.3.jar and added that jar to "C:\Users\VAIBHAV-PC.m2\repository\org\hsqldb\hsqldb\2.3.3\".After adding that jar hsqldb jar error was solved.But still, i am getting error for my custom jar 'com.ResponceGenerator does not exist '

Comment: You'll do better if you pull everything from Maven Central.  Maven usually puts more than the JAR in that directory.  That's likely to be your problem.  Have you ever used Maven before?

Comment: @talex, I am using below steps to invoke Maven,
Run As->Maven Build->then enter(clean install)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you upload the pom.xml of the SpringBoot Project ? Below is the example. Also make sure the custom jar is in your local maven repository.

Project A pom.xml ( Add the below plugin)

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <classifier>exec</classifier>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Project B pom.xml (Add  your local repo information and include Project A under dependency section)

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>local-repo</id>
        <url>file:${user.home}\.m2\repository</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Project A Information

Comment: I can't able to attach my pom.xml code because limited character's length.

Comment: I want to create a jar from java project for some specific functionality, so whenever I want to use that functionality again then I just need to attach that  Jar to my project.can you provide a link from where I can learn more about it.